# How to remove paperclip uploaded file attachment from record during form update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a rails application, i already uploaded a image attachment in the record **A**.
i want to edit the record **A** and also want to remove the attachment from record **A**.
The paperclip attachment used same in record **A** model

In the edit form how to remove the attachement during the form submition(update record)?

Any one have a an simple answer?

Comment: According to paperclip doc if you need to remove the file then you can simply set your attachment to `nil`. Like `@user.avatar = nil`. https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/README.md#quick-start